Dataflow: Warning in WriteToBigQuery
I have a pipeline which is receiving streaming data via pub/sub.
The data is manipulated and I want to write in BigQuery, using dynamic tables based on the row information:
table=lambda element: f'{GCP_PROJECT}:{element.get("customerId").replace("-","_")}.{element.get("siteId")}',
pipeline below:
        # ----------------------------------
        #     Write to BgQuery Pipeline
        # ----------------------------------
        bq_results = (
            pipeline_bq
            | 'Add Timestamp' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(elem, int(elem['measurement_time'])))
            | 'Window into window_size Seconds' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(window_size), allowed_lateness=beam.window.Duration(seconds=120))
            | 'creating tupple' >> beam.Map(lambda element: ((element.get("customerId", "").replace("-", "_"), element.get("siteId", "")), element))
            | 'Group by customerId and networkId' >> beam.GroupByKey()

            # Option 1 - Write directly
            | 'Extract Values from Tupple' >> beam.Map(lambda kv: kv[1])
            | 'Flatten List (BigQuery expects one individual row)' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda values: values)
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=lambda element: f'{GCP_PROJECT}:{element.get("customerId").replace("-","_")}.{element.get("siteId")}',
                schema=schema,
                method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
                triggering_frequency=120,
                with_auto_sharding=True,
                batch_size=500,
                additional_bq_parameters={
                    'timePartitioning':
                        {
                            'type': 'DAY',
                            'field': 'measurement_time'
                        },
                    'clustering':
                        {
                            'fields': ['node_address']
                        }

                },
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
            )
        )

Everything is working, but I'm getting the above warning saying that the process is taking long time to execute:
Operation ongoing in bundle process_bundle-70-183 for PTransform{name=Write to BigQuery/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-59, state=process-msecs} for at least 3336.47 seconds without outputting or completing

Two questions:

Why is it taking so long to Stream the rows into BigQuery
How can I optimise the write? I tried several options and I'm doing the GroupByKey to try to aggregate the similar rows, but still, it's taking long time

Suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks

Is the write heavy? In general, STORAGE_WRITE_API
is recommended (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/write-to-bigquery#overview)
